# If $\mathbb E(X)=\mathbb E\left(X^2\right)=0$ show that $\mathbb P(X=0)=1$

Tags: probability-theory

Can anyone help me with this problem?

I want to show that if $\mathbb E(X)=\mathbb E\left(X^2\right)=0$ then $\mathbb P(X=0)=1$.

I was thinking to use Markov's inequality as this:
$\mathbb P\left(X<\dfrac1n\right)\le\dfrac{\mathbb E(X)}{1/n}=0$ so, $\mathbb P(X=0)=1$.

I am not sure.

Comment: The variance of X: $V(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2=0$. If the variance of X is 0 then $X=E(X)$ a.s. so $X=0$ a.s. Thus $P(X=0)=1$

Comment: I think you could use a similar method as the above, but with Chebyshev's inequality instead. You seem to assume in your argument that $X$ is a non-negative random variable (if you don't know it, see https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_2_2_markov_chebyshev_inequalities.php).

Comment: So you didn't use Markovs inequality? And why X=E(X)?

Comment: Note that Markov's inequality only works for non-negative random variables.  You aren't told $X$ is non-negative (which is also why your argument seemed to apply even without knowing $E(X^2)=0$).  If you don't know chebyshev's, apply markov's to $(X-E(X))^2$

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use Markov inequality. If $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 0$, you must have $$\int_{x}x^2 f(x) dx = 0$$ As $x^2$ is always non-negative, it cannot be the case that $f(x) > 0$ and $x^2 > 0$ simultaneously, so for all $x^2 > 0$ we must have $f(x) = 0$. This, in turn, means $\mathbb{P}[X^2 > 0] = 0 \implies \mathbb{P}[X^2 = 0] = 1 \implies \mathbb{P}[X = 0] = 1$.